# Pattern all words must be present in regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to match a pattern in which two words must be present, but I cannot make my regex work.

The result is null. Why?

```
select 'only test bla dido simple' REGEXP '^(\\?=.*\\?(simple))(\\?=.*\\?(only))*$';
```

Comment: i want mutch 2 word(simple and only) from string "onty test dido simple", but i bekomme no result like this:<br />                          +---------------------------------------------+<br />
| 'only test simple' REGEXP '^(\\?=.*\\?(simple))(\\?=.*\\?only))*$'<br /> |
+----------------------------------------------+<br/>
|                                            0 |<br />
+----------------------------------------------+<br />

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  It is helpful here to use some formality in your questions: this system serves as an archive to help others with similar questions. I have edited your question to help do that.  Also, you should accept the answer that helped you, by revisiting the question and clicking on the green checkbox next to that answer.

Comment: Abdelillah Farka - The following apply for each answer to **your** question: Left from the answer is a big number (that represents up/down votes) with up/down arrows (for voting by qualified users). When you hover your mouse pointer below the down arrow, check mark will appear. If you check on it, the color will change to green and by doing that you accept such answer. That is what you should do. No stakes for free. SO users deserve be accepted for help. Go back to your previous questions and do that NOW!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For words **simple** and **only** the regular regex would be `^(?=.*\bsimple\b)(?=.*\bonly\b).*$`.

To accept this regex by *mysql* you have to add escape `\` characters as needed - that is now task for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually zero, not `NULL`. The MySQL `REGEXP` operator returns 0 for nonmatch and 1 for match. (As you know, `NULL` has a specific meaning in the world of RDBMS.)

So the question is, what does your particular regexp match? Let us deconstruct it.

```
 '^(\\?=.*\\?(simple))(\\?=.*\\?(only))*$'
```

It begins with `^` and ends with `$`, so it must match the entire string, not a substring.

It consists of two concatenated expressions, both of the form

```
(\\?=.*\\?(word))
```

As far as I can tell, you want to match:

1. An optional backslash
2. An equals sign
3. Any string of characters zero length or more, gobbling the input
4. Another optional backslash
5. The word

I cannot figure out what you hope to accomplish with this complex sequence of matches. There aren't any equals signs in your input text.

You could use this statement. Of course it returns zero because the word simple comes after the word only in your input text.

```
 SELECT 'only test bla dido simple' REGEXP '^.*(simple).*(only).*$'
```

MySQL doesn't handle `(?=pattern)` lookahead expressions, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: but moment my result is zero :-(

Comment: @ollie jones what is the workaround for (?=pattern) lookahead in mysql?